# Search elements including roots and descendents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ecmascript-6

What's a good way to search a small set of elements structured like this? I want to be able to find any element given its ID, without having to know exactly where I'm looking for it.

```
const elements = $(`
   <div id="a">
      <div id="aa"></div>
      <div id="ab"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="b">
      <div id="ba"></div>
      <div id="bb"></div>
   </div>
`);
```

- `.find("#id")` can find `aa`, but not `a` or `b`
- `.filter("#id")` can find `a` and `b`, but not `aa` or `bb`
- I also tried `.siblings().addBack().find("#id")`, but that doesn't seem to work either (can't even find `a`)

I can't seem to get around the fact that `find` misses the root elements, but `filter` misses the descendent elements. I need some combination of the two...

Comment: Is always used the format parent letter + next letter?

Comment: @mbadeveloper no, that's just for example to describe the heirarchy

Comment: But always will be a div parent and div child's?

Comment: @mbadeveloper it should be able to go to any depth, not just two levels.

Comment: What I suggest is to use $("div") and create a function recursive function and pass it the current element and check if have childs

Comment: is this what you need? 
$('div').each(function(){
  if(this.id) console.log(this.id);
});

Comment: @mbadeveloper they aren't necessarily all `div` elements, sorry, that's just for example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ah, you're right, thanks. `find` is searching the children of all root elements, it's just skipping the root elements. `filter` searches the root elements, but skips the children. (I was thinking `find` was only searching the first element's children for some reason.) This enables me to improve my solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess ultimately the solution is simply to use both `find` and `filter` and just check both. Together they will search everything.

```
const search = `#${elementName}`;

const maybeAtRoots = elements.filter(search);
if (maybeAtRoots.length)
   return maybeAtRoots;

const maybeUnderRoots = elements.find(search);
if (maybeUnderRoots.length)
   return maybeUnderRoots;

throw new Error(`failed to find element '${elementName}'`);
```

Comment: something wrong with this solution? this code is working.

Comment: I've improved the solution slightly thanks to feedback from comments on the question.

Comment: I dunno why I get a negative score, "use both filter and find" is the obvious and correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery 1.11.2 and 2.1.2 onwards you can effectively use a `documentFragment` like this:

```
$(document.createDocumentFragment())
```

This does not introduce an element. If you append the `element` contents to it, and query the parent of `#a` you'll get no match.

```js
var elements = $(`
   <div id="a">
      <div id="aa"></div>
      <div id="ab"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="b">
      <div id="ba"></div>
      <div id="bb"></div>
   </div>
`);

// wrap elements in a document fragment
elements = $(document.createDocumentFragment()).append(elements);

// elements.find('#a') works, but second argument of $() can be used: 
console.log('#a', $('#a', elements).length);
console.log('#ab', $('#ab', elements).length);
console.log('#ba', $('#ba', elements).length);

console.log('parents of #a:', $('#a', elements).parent().length);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well.. the only problem with this is that if I hang on to the document fragment reference, it is blanked as soon as I add it to the page. When doing a manual search I was able to keep my elements reference and use it as needed. Thanks though, I was unaware of `document.createDocumentFragment`.

Comment: If you want to retain the document fragment even after adding it to the document, then clone it: `$('body').append(elements.clone());` Of course, you'll be working with a different copy then, not with the nodes in the document. A node cannot be part of the document and of a document fragment at the same time.